# How to prove that the partial derivative with respect to x equals zero using derivative definition?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, infinity

Given that $f(0,0) = 0$:

How is it possible that $$\frac{∂f}{∂x}(0,0)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac1h\big(f(0+ h,0)−f(0,0)\big)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac1h\!\cdot\!0=0$$

I assume they did
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac1h\big(f(0+h,0)−f(0,0)\big)=$$
$$=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac1h\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}\big(f(0+h,0)−f(0,0)\big)=$$
$$=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac1h\!\cdot\!0=0$$

**But** $$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac1h=\infty$$

So how does zero times infinity equal zero? I thought multiplication with infinity was undefined.

Edit: The suggested post doesn't answer my question since my assumption is wrong. I wanted help with understanding how the partial derivative with respect to x is 0. Since this site requires us to show our own work I had to show you my take on it which is clearly wrong.The title has also been edited now to better suit the actual problem.

Comment: Isn't it $\frac{f(h,0)}{h}$ instead of $\frac1h$ ? Then the limits depends on $f$.

Comment: @Lelouch what do you mean?

Comment: You can't say anything about the limit of $f$ at $(0,0)$ if all you know is the value of $f$ at $(0,0)$. There must be information that you have not told us.

Comment: Just to be clear, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (0, 0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\left( \frac1{h} (f(0 + h, 0) − f(0, 0)) \right)$. It's not $\left(\lim_{h \to 0} \frac1{h}\right) (f(0 + h, 0) − f(0, 0))$.

Comment: @DavidK Aha no in an earlier question, I have proven that f is continuous at (0,0)

Comment: @Need_MathHelp: That's irrelevant (or at least not enough information). The missing information that David K is talking about must be that $f(h,0)=0$ for *all* $h$ (not just for $h=0$). Otherwise your first calculation doesn't make sense. (And your second calculation *never* makes sense, since the “product of the limits” rule doesn't apply to the case “$\infty \cdot 0$”.)

Comment: And by the way, $\lim_{h \to 0} (1/h)$ is *not* equal to $\infty$ (in the context of the extended real line). It doesn't exist, since $\lim_{h \to 0^-} (1/h) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{h \to 0^+} (1/h) = +\infty$ are unequal.

Comment: "... in an earlier question, I have proven ..." And you didn't think we deserved to see a link to that question? Did you expect us to guess that such a question existed and go hunt it down, or perhaps use telepathy? Next time, link to the earlier question within the new question, like this: [How to check if the limit exists in multivariable calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4706909/139123).

Comment: In the linked question, $f(0+h,0)=0$ also for all $h$, which is the missing information.

Comment: @DavidK No I was confused, looking back at the question I totally did something else (never proved that $f(0+h, 0)$ goes to zero'9 so now I am even more confused as to how they got $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$. For the record my earlier post "How to check if the limit exists in multivariable calculus" is another question not related to this one.

Comment: I wrote, "In the linked question, $f(0+h,0)=0$ also for all $h$," not because it the other question literally said so but because I looked at **the function defined in that question** and was able to conclude that fact. But I did jump to the conclusion that the question you posted before was about the same function $f$ and was therefore related to this one. Is this question about a new function? If so, we really need to know what that function is. I see you've been active here and you seem to know how to ask a good question; I'm surprised that you're having such difficulty asking this one.

Comment: You are right, I usually post the entire question so it doesn't become the famous "xy-problem". But this time I was only confused about this part of the problem and forgot to realize that you guys need more than just this to work with. Sorry for the confusion Ig:) I've been solving a lot of problems lately so I don't even know where I found this question and thus I can't really edit it. But I stumbled on a similar question where this was not the case so I just wanted once again to confirm if my assumption of what they did was wrong?

Comment: It's unfortunate that you've lost track of the source of this particular question. But if the source is lost, it is lost, and there is not much you can do about that. The only thing I can think that is left to say is that it is unlikely that someone teaching math would make the mistake of factoring a limit into the product of an undefined limit and zero. It is much more likely that $f(0+h,0)=0$ for $h$ in some neighborhood of $0$ (and only slightly less likely that the neighborhood is all of $\mathbb R$), which leads to $\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac1h\cdot0\right)=\lim_{h\to0}0=0.$